# How to retrieve script fields along with other fields from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to dynamically calculate some values and retrieve the calculated values along with the original fields instead of only calculated. Say, there are fields "userId", "value". Additionally, I would like to calculate "additionalParameter". In order to do that, the following simple script has been added:

```
"query": {
    "match": {
            "userId": "1161851"
        }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "additionalParameter": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['value'] * factor",
        "params": {
        "factor": 2.0
    }
      }
    }
  }
```

When the above query is executed, however, I get only additionalParameter:

```
{
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "dd57ba66-a31a-45f1-9948-18ff4fb27dc1",
        "_score" : 3.0488422,
        "fields" : {
          "additionalParameter" : [
            10.0
          ]
        }
      },
...
```

Does anyone know what is the right way to append calculated values to original fields and retrieve all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a _source in the query

```
{
  "stored_fields": [
    "_source"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match": {
            "userId": "1161851"
        }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "additionalParameter": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['value'] * factor",
        "params": {
        "factor": 2.0
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```